# Ingress with Google Kubernetes, rules are not working as expected

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, gke-networking

I referred the below link from Google for my implementation
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/load-balance-ingress

I am using ingress-gce to enable access to the frontend and backend.

frontend is a react based application where service is of type NodePort
backedn is a nodeJS based application where service is of type NodePort

below is the ingress configuration

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: ia-dev-ip
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  name: ia-prod-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: ia-prod-landingpage-deploy-service
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /cms(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: ia-prod-cms-deploy-service
              servicePort: 80
```

below is the details i receive when i do
kubectl describe ing ia-prod-ingress

```
Name:             ia-prod-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          xx.xxx.xx.xx
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (aa.aa.aa.aa:8080)
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  *
        /(.*)           ia-prod-landingpage-deploy-service:80 (bb.bb.bb.bb:80)
        /cms(/|$)(.*)   ia-prod-cms-deploy-service:80 (cc.cc.cc.cc:8080)
Annotations:
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"nginx","kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name":"ia-dev-ip","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target":"/$1"},"name":"ia-prod-ingress","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"ia-prod-landingpage-deploy-service","servicePort":80},"path":"/(.*)"},{"backend":{"serviceName":"ia-prod-cms-deploy-service","servicePort":80},"path":"/cms(/|$)(.*)"}]}}]}}

  kubernetes.io/ingress.class:                  nginx
  kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name:  ia-dev-ip
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:   /$1
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                  From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----                 ----                      -------
  Normal  CREATE  20m                  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/ia-prod-ingress
  Normal  UPDATE  3m30s (x7 over 19m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/ia-prod-ingress
```

when i visit the URLs with the ip address i receive from the ingress-gce like below

http://ipaddress/ --> frontend application is loading as expected.

http://ipaddress/cms --> I am expecting the backend application to respond.
however even on http://ipaddress/cms frontend application is loading ..

any idea, what correction is needed to access the backend?

Below is the yaml file of ingress configuration that worked for me to resolve the correct paths to all the components

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: ia-dev-ip
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  name: ia-prod-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
    - host: xx.yy.zzz.yy.xip.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: ia-prod-landingpage-deploy-service
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /cms/(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: ia-prod-cms-deploy-service
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /tablegenerator/(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: ia-prod-metabase-deploy-service
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /wrapperservice/(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: ia-prod-wrapperservice-deploy-service
              servicePort: 80
```

Comment: is your app serving on `/cms`?

Comment: @suren: if try to access like below 
[link](http://35.201.102.54/cms)  --> I am expecting the backend to respond but i get 
Cannot GET /cms

if try [link](http://35.201.102.54/cms/)  --> frontend is loading 
front end is loading also on [link](http://35.201.102.54/)

Comment: to suffice your requirements , could you please try with just / , remove the start from frontend rule and check.

Comment: Please update your question with output of the command: `$ kubectl describe ing ia-dev-ingress`. If the path will be set to: `/` it will **only** work for `/`. If request will have anything besides `/`, like `/asd` it will get sent back with 404. The path of `/cms` will **only** work for request with `/cms`. It will not work for requests like: `/cms/` or `/cms/asd`. To resolve it you can modify your existing rules to better match the requests you are sending like `/cms/*`, `/cms/`, `/cms`, `/*`. You could also use `nginx-ingress-controller`. Please tell if you are okay with using it.

Comment: @Santhosha I get 404, which is what I would expect if my server wouldn't be serving on `/cms`.

Comment: @taurn khosla : I have tried with / for frontend and /cms for backend , but the problem persists, I am using the ingress-gce (default implementation by google with out nginx-ingress-controller)

Comment: @DawidKruk : I am not using the nginx-ingress-controller at the moment, as we do not have static ip address to use for nginx-ingress-controller, as soon as we have one , will try switching to 'nginx-ingress-controller' and try again

and at the moment i am only checking if the application rechable via ingress for both frontend and backend with / for frontend and /cms for backend ... / is working for frontend /cms is returning 404 for backend

Comment: As I said please update your post with: `$ kubectl describe ing ia-dev-ingress`. We should be able to see if the `Ingress` resource is configured correctly. Also if it happened that the request to `/cms` would require anything besides `/cms` in path, the request would go to the frontend not the backend.

Comment: @DawidKruk: i switched to nginx-ingress controller now instead of default ingress controller from google, now on [link](http://ipaddress/)  i am able to reach the frontend and [link](http://ipaddress/cms/) i am able to reach the backend ... but as the backend is an REST API project if add anything after http://ipaddress/cms/api-docs it is taking me back to frontend ... any clues here?

I have updated the yaml used for ingress and description of the same via kubectl

Comment: Hello. Sorry for such late response. The annotation of  `kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: ia-dev-ip` is designed to work with `ingress-gce` not the `nginx-ingress`. This annotation will not work. The entrypoint will be the `LoadBalancer` type of service of your `nginx-ingress-controller`. Can you give the example of such a request that is taking you back to the frontend and it should go to the backend?

Comment: @DawidKruk: I have resolved the rules now, I have updated the working ingress file now..

only part i have to address now is to use the static IP address for the loadbalancer when i use ingress-nginx controller.

Comment: You can allocate a static IP address on GCP and edit the service of type `LoadBalancer` of the `nginx-ingress-controller` to enter the newly created IP address (`loadBalancerIP` field). Please take a look on this link: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip#step_2_expose_your_application .  Let me know if you've managed to make it work.